# Reasons to use array.resize instead of redim

Tags: .net, arrays, vb.net

I know that "redim" is older than "Array.Resize" but do not understand the reasons that make better to use the latter to the former.

Comment: There is never any reason.  As soon as you *start* thinking about Redim/Resize, you should immediately substitute with List(Of T).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot possibly compare [ReDim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w8k3cys2.aspx) and [Array.Resize<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051(v=vs.110).aspx) *unless* you add the `Preserve` modifier.

`Array.Resize` will not only allocate a new array, but also copies all the items in the source array to the target array.

`ReDim` without the `Preserve` modifier will only allocate a new array. All the items in the source array is lost.

So basicly this:

```
Dim a As String() = {"item1", "item2"}
ReDim a(4 - 1) 'Double the size
'At this point, a contains 4 null references.
```

... is equal to this:

```
Dim a As String() = {"item1", "item2"}
a = New String(4 - 1) {} 'Double the size
'At this point, a contains 4 null references.
```

You can verify this by inspecting the produced [CIL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Common_Intermediate_Language) code from release configuration and look for the [0x8D - newarr <etype>](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_CIL_instructions) instruction. By knowing this it's quite obvious as to why this is faster than `Array.Resize<T>`.

So instead, let's compare `ReDim Preserve` and `Array<T>`.

> So which one to use?

Let's create two methods and look at the `CIL` code.

**VB.NET**

```
Private Sub ResizeArray1(Of T)(ByRef a As T(), size As Int32)
    ReDim Preserve a(size - 1)
End Sub

Private Sub ResizeArray2(Of T)(ByRef a As T(), size As Int32)
    Array.Resize(a, size)
End Sub
```

**CIL**

```
.method private static void ResizeArray1<T>(!!T[]& a, int32 size) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldarg.0 
    L_0002: ldind.ref 
    L_0003: ldarg.1 
    L_0004: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0005: sub.ovf 
    L_0006: ldc.i4.1 
    L_0007: add.ovf 
    L_0008: newarr !!T
    L_000d: call class [mscorlib]System.Array [Microsoft.VisualBasic]Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Utils::CopyArray(class [mscorlib]System.Array, class [mscorlib]System.Array)
    L_0012: castclass !!T[]
    L_0017: stind.ref 
    L_0018: ret 
}

.method private static void ResizeArray2<T>(!!T[]& a, int32 size) cil managed
{
    .maxstack 8
    L_0000: ldarg.0 
    L_0001: ldarg.1 
    L_0002: call void [mscorlib]System.Array::Resize<!!T>(!!0[]&, int32)
    L_0007: ret 
}
```

As you can see `ReDim Preserve` ends up as a call instruction to [Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.Utils.CopyArray](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#Microsoft.VisualBasic/Microsoft/VisualBasic/CompilerServices/Utils.cs,1e11bde7fa0a8c77). Now, if you inspect `CopyArray` (source code not available at RS) and [Array.Resize<T>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,71074deaf111c4e3) you'll see that both methods ends up as a call instruction to [Array.Copy<T>](http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/array.cs,757884fad3fffbe4) which is a [CLR](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8bs2ecf4(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

So one can argue that they are both essentially "identical", and a quick benckmark (available at the end of this post) seems to confirm this.

However, as correctly noted by Hans Passant, you should rather be using a [List<T>](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19(v=vs.110).aspx) whenever you need to manipulate an array.

---

**Benchmark**

> Iterations: 10
>   MaxSize: 100000
>
> Empty source array:
>
> { Method = ResizeArray1, Time = 00:00:05.6533126 }
>   { Method = ResizeArray2, Time = 00:00:05.6973607 }
>
> Growing source array:
>
> { Method = ResizeArray1, Time = 00:01:42.6964858 }
>   { Method = ResizeArray2, Time = 00:01:42.1891668 }

```
Option Strict On

Public Module Program

    Friend Sub Main()
        Console.WriteLine("Warming up...")
        Program.Benchmark(iterations:=10, maxSize:=1000, warmUp:=True)
        Console.WriteLine("Warmup completed. Measurement started...")
        Program.Benchmark(iterations:=10, maxSize:=100000, warmUp:=False)
        Console.WriteLine()
        Console.WriteLine("Measurement completed. Press any key to exit.")
        Console.ReadKey()
    End Sub

    Private Sub Benchmark(iterations As Int32, maxSize As Int32, warmUp As Boolean)

        Dim watch As Stopwatch
        Dim a As String()

        'BY: EMPTY SOURCE ARRAY --------------------------------- 

        'Resize array #1

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

        For i As Int32 = 1 To iterations
            For n As Int32 = 1 To maxSize
                a = Program.CreateArray(Of String)(0)
                Program.ResizeArray1(a, n)
            Next
        Next

        watch.Stop()

        If (Not warmUp) Then
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("R E S U L T"))
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("Iterations: {0}", iterations))
            Console.WriteLine(String.Format("   MaxSize: {0}", maxSize))
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Empty source array:")
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine(New With {.Method = "ResizeArray1", .Time = watch.Elapsed.ToString()})
        End If

        'Resize array #2

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()

        For i As Int32 = 1 To iterations
            For n As Int32 = 1 To maxSize
                a = CreateArray(Of String)(0)
                ResizeArray2(a, n)
            Next
        Next

        watch.Stop()

        If (Not warmUp) Then
            Console.WriteLine(New With {.Method = "ResizeArray2", .Time = watch.Elapsed.ToString()})
        End If

        'BY: GROWING SOURCE ARRAY -------------------------------

        'Resize array #1

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        a = Program.CreateArray(Of String)(0)

        For i As Int32 = 1 To iterations
            For n As Int32 = 1 To maxSize
                Program.ResizeArray1(a, n)
            Next
        Next

        watch.Stop()

        If (Not warmUp) Then
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine("Growing source array:")
            Console.WriteLine()
            Console.WriteLine(New With {.Method = "ResizeArray1", .Time = watch.Elapsed.ToString()})
        End If

        'Resize array #2

        watch = Stopwatch.StartNew()
        a = Program.CreateArray(Of String)(0)

        For i As Int32 = 1 To iterations
            For n As Int32 = 1 To maxSize
                Program.ResizeArray2(a, n)
            Next
        Next

        watch.Stop()

        If (Not warmUp) Then
            Console.WriteLine(New With {.Method = "ResizeArray2", .Time = watch.Elapsed.ToString()})
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Function CreateArray(Of T)(size As Int32) As T()
        Return New T(size - 1) {}
    End Function

    Private Sub ResizeArray1(Of T)(ByRef a As T(), size As Int32)
        ReDim Preserve a(size - 1)
    End Sub

    Private Sub ResizeArray2(Of T)(ByRef a As T(), size As Int32)
        Array.Resize(a, size)
    End Sub

End Module
```

Comment: I read your post (and also your comment to first answer) but what do you think about the "Custom Array-Resize solution" is it really useful?

Comment: @genespos I highly doubt it. The fastest way is probably to create a new array instance and call `Array.Copy` directly. A quick benchmark (release config) seems to confirm this. In fact, it's the fastest, while the custom method is the slowest.

Answer (score 3):

As explained in MSDN, **[ReDim](https://msdn.microsoft.com/es-es/library/w8k3cys2%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)** and **[Array.Resize](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)** seems to work equal by allocationg a new Array with fixed size to copy the contents of the old awwat, however there are some internal differences (that I ignore) that makes `ReDim` faster, and `ReDim Preserve` a performance killer when compared.

By the result of the next test, which performs a simple iteration to redimensionate an array 100.000 times, you can proof that `ReDim` is much faster than `Array.Resize`, however, both are slower than a custom generic solution using `Array.Copy` method.

---

### Results

> ReDim Elapsed Time: 00:00:07.3918219
>
> Array.Resize Elapsed Time: 00:00:28.9773317
>
> Custom Resize Elapsed Time: 00:00:03.2659880

As you see, there is a difference of +20 seconds between `ReDim` and `Array.Resize`

---

### Test source-code

```
Dim myArray As String()
Dim sw As New Stopwatch

myArray = New String() {"Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"}
sw.Start()
For x As Integer = 1 To 100000 : ReDim myArray(x) : Next
sw.Stop()
Console.WriteLine("ReDim Elapsed Time: " & sw.Elapsed.ToString)

myArray = New String() {"Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"}
sw.Restart()
For x As Integer = 1 To 100000 : Array.Resize(myArray, x) : Next
sw.Stop()
Console.WriteLine("Array.Resize Elapsed Time: " & sw.Elapsed.ToString)

myArray = New String() {"Q", "W", "E", "R", "T", "Y"}
sw.Restart()
For x As Integer = 1 To 100000 : ResizeArray(myArray, x) : Next
sw.Stop()
Console.WriteLine("Custom Resize Elapsed Time: " & sw.Elapsed.ToString)
```

---

### Custom Array-Resize solution:

Very useful to add it as a extension method.

```
' <Extension>
<DebuggerStepThrough>
Public Function ResizeArray(Of T)(ByVal sender As T(),
                                  ByVal newSize As Integer) As T()

    If (newSize <= 0) Then
        Throw New ArgumentOutOfRangeException(paramName:="newSize",
                                              message:="Value bigger than 0 is required.")
    End If

    Dim preserveLength As Integer = Math.Min(sender.Length, newSize)

    If (preserveLength > 0) Then
        Dim newArray As Array = Array.CreateInstance(sender.GetType.GetElementType, newSize)
        Array.Copy(sender, newArray, preserveLength)
        Return DirectCast(newArray, T())

    Else
        Return sender

    End If

End Function
```

Disclaimer: I'm not the author of the function, it is a custom Vb.Net adapttaion from a C# code that I found time ago in a random StackOverflow answer about Array.Resize performance.

Comment: Thanks for you answer and for your code: I'll test it as soon as possible ;)

Comment: There's a very big flaw in your bechmark. You're not setting the return value of `ResizeArray(myArray, x)` so you're always working with the initial array (6 elements). The argument in `Array.Resize` is by reference so it works as it should. Apply the changes `myArray = ResizeArray(myArray, x)` and you'll get a different (but correct) result.

Comment: You're right @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå, this are the results!
'ReDim Elapsed Time: 00:00:02.3281857
ReDim Preserve Elapsed Time: 00:00:09.0978561
Array.Resize Elapsed Time: 00:00:17.3862156
Custom Resize Elapsed Time: 00:00:17.5181313'

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure but I seem to remember that resize will work on the array directly whereas redim will create a new array at the new size and then copy values from old into the new and then dispose of the old and rename the new. I.e. considerably more processing.

Comment: So array.redim is faster? I saw that array.redim works byref

Comment: I don't think so... why would they introduce something that is inferior.

Comment: @Mych no, both Array.Resize and ReDim will allocate a new array to copy the entire old-array. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb348051%28v=vs.110%29.aspx